# Reference request: Variational techniques for complex "iterated" Lagrangians

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations

I am interested in solving variational problems of the form
$$
\min_u \int \Big\{L(x,y,u(x,y)) + \phi\Big(\int J(z,y,u(z,y))\,dz\Big)\Big\} p(x,y)\,dx\,dy.
$$
for some known, smooth functions $L,J,\phi,p$, and the minimization is with respect to functions $u:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. We can assume e.g. $u$ is square integrable or even bounded; this part isn't crucial. Note that the derivatives of $u$ are not involved, which helps simplify things somewhat.

For example, a particular form that has come up is the following:
$$
\min_u \int \Big\{g(x) + \Big(\int h(z) u(z,y)\,dz\Big)^r\Big\} p(x,y)\, dx\,dy
$$

There is some structure here (e.g. the double integral involving two Lagrangian functions) that seems ripe for exploitation. But the second, inner integral seems to break the standard setup of the calculus of variations (what is the derivative of $\int J(z,y,u(z,y))\,dz$ with respect to $u$?), but maybe I am missing something.

I am looking for any references covering these types of problems, or related ones. I would also be interested in (even more complicated) formulations involving derivatives of $u$, but the simpler version seems difficult enough!

**EDIT:** It seems that the most salient aspects of this problem can be exposed by considering the simpler form
$$
\min_u \int \phi\Big(\int J(z,y,u(z,y))\,dz\Big)\,dy.
$$
From this angle, it is clear that $\phi$ is the complication (e.g. if $\phi$ were not involved, this would be a standard calculus of variations problem).

Comment: It will.be better for reader comprehension if you replace the argument x in J with some other dummy variable.

Comment: The keyword you should search for is 'nonlocal variational calclus'

Comment: Nonlocal problems are a pretty broad topic, so if you have any more specific suggestions I'd love to take a look!

Comment: When $\phi$ is the $r$-th power, with $r\in\mathbb{N}$, you could rewrite it as a regular variational problem by "splitting" $z$ into $r$ different variables $(\int F(z)dz)^r =\int F(z_1)\cdots F(z_r)dz_1 \cdots dz_r$.

Answer (score 1):

At least if everything is sufficiently smooth,
$$
\frac{\delta }{\delta u(s,t)} \int dy\ \phi \left( \int dz\ J(z,y,u(z,y)) \right) = \phi^{\prime } \left( \int dz\ J(z,t,u(z,t)) \right) \frac{\partial J}{\partial u} (s,t,u(s,t))
$$